# How to clone jQuery library (copy by value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to clone the full jQuery object. I tried using `_.clone()`, `_.cloneDeep()` (underscore or lodash) but it's not just an object, it's a function.

The aim is to provide jQuery to my clients who use my library by giving a copy of it, not a reference, because I don't want them to mess up my own jQuery (the lib is sandboxed) so they don't have to inject another script but just calling one of the functions I'd provide to get a jQuery they can use.

Comment: _.clone() in underscore is a shallow copy. _.cloneDeep() in lodash should create a deep clone.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve makes no sense.

Comment: @Vohuman Why not? If passing jQuery by reference, a sandboxed script could replace `$.ajax`, for example, and therefore be able to run code outside its sandbox.

Comment: @Siguza Exactly. I want to avoid my lib to be modified by external sources, to prevent bugs but also to prevent malicious code to run on a supposed secured sandbox.

Comment: @Apha That's what I thought at first, maybe it didn't work because I used a older version of Lodash as stated in Siguza's answer.

Comment: @Vadorequest hey dude see for the **.noconflict()** i think you can you this for your purpose. **https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/** or just by assigning the jquery object value to a variable

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that your code is a plugin itself, and you don't want to "mess up" `<head>`, I assume that you must also not modify the original `$`/`jQuery` at any time, and instead load your instance of jQuery directly into a new variable.

I think I managed to fully do that.
The below code works as follows:

First, the jQuery code is fetched with an XHR.
Next, a `proxy` variable is constructed by iterating over all properties of `window` and adding wrappers for functions, and getters/setters for properties.
The `try`/`catch` is necessary to silently skip properties that would otherwise cause an error, such as:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'caches' property from 'Window': Cache storage is disabled because the context is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
```

Also note that `$` and `jQuery` are explicitly excluded.

In order for jQuery not to overwrite `window.$` and `window.jQuery`, we need to change to where `window` points, because jQuery explicitly sets `window.$` and `window.jQuery`.
But we can't change `window`, because it's read-only.
What we **can** do, however, is to name a function argument `window`.

```
~function(window)
{
    /* in here, window == proxy */
}(proxy);
```

So last, an anonymous function is called with `proxy` as argument, which turns to `window` inside that function, where the jQuery code is finally evaluated.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js');
xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e)
{
    var proxy = {};
    for(var key in window)
    {
        if(key !== '$' && key !== 'jQuery')
        {
            ~function(k)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(typeof window[k] === 'function')
                    {
                        proxy[k] = function()
                        {
                            window[k].apply(window, arguments);
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Object.defineProperty(proxy, k,
                        {
                            get: function()
                            {
                                return window[k];
                            },
                            set: function(val)
                            {
                                window[k] = val;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch(error){}
            }(key);
        }
    }
    ~function(window)
    {
        eval(e.target.responseText);
    }(proxy);
    $.test = 'meow';
    document.write($.test + '<br>');
    document.write(proxy.$.test + '<br>');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys($('body'))) + '<br>');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(proxy.$('body'))) + '<br>');
});
xhr.send();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now, I **think** that `proxy` works 100% like jQuery expects it to, however I **can't guarantee** it.
You should do exhaustive testing before using this in production.

**But what about "actual" cloning?**

I'm quite certain that there is no way around loading jQuery a second time.
The exported `$`/`jQuery` function has access to a lot of closures, none of which any "outsider" JS code could clone, or even access.
The only way to "clone jQuery" would be to call the anonymous function again, in which it is defined/exported, but that function is not available.
`$.toString()` also returns nothing of use, as it refers to many closures, and would only throw a ton of exceptions when `eval`'d.

---

## Previous answer:

You can store a reference of `$` or `jQuery` in a variable, delete `window.$` and `window.jQuery`, and simply append another `<script>` tag to `document.head`, with `src` set to the jQuery file.
You'd end up with two copies of jQuery as well:

```js
var myQuery = jQuery;
delete window.jQuery;
delete window.$;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js';
script.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    jQuery.test = 'meow';
    document.write($.test + '<br>');
    document.write(myQuery.test + '<br>');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys($('body'))) + '<br>');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(myQuery('body'))) + '<br>');
});
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it hurts a bit to even propose this... but it **can** be done with XHR + eval too, of course... not saying it **should**, though.

```js
var myQuery = jQuery;
delete window.jQuery;
delete window.$;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js');
xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e)
{
    eval(e.target.responseText);
    jQuery.test = 'meow';
    document.write($.test + '<br>');
    document.write(myQuery.test + '<br>');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys($('body'))) + '<br>');
    document.write(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(myQuery('body'))) + '<br>');
});
xhr.send();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

## Legacy/Lodash:

It looks like Lodash is *not* capable of doing this!

Lodash 2.4.2 (and lower, presumably) will simply reference any functions:

```js
var a = function(){};
document.write('a.a before setting b.a: ' + a.a + ' (expected: undefined)<br>');
var b = _.cloneDeep(a);
b.a = 'a';
document.write('a.a after setting b.a: ' + a.a + ' (expected: undefined)<br>');
document.write('type of a: ' + (typeof a) + ' (expected: function)<br>');
document.write('type of b: ' + (typeof b) + ' (expected: function)<br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Lodash 3.0.0 (and higher, presumable) might at first seem to work, but only until you realise that functions don't stay functions:

```js
var a = function(){};
document.write('a.a before setting b.a: ' + a.a + ' (expected: undefined)<br>');
var b = _.cloneDeep(a);
b.a = 'a';
document.write('a.a after setting b.a: ' + a.a + ' (expected: undefined)<br>');
document.write('type of a: ' + (typeof a) + ' (expected: function)<br>');
document.write('type of b: ' + (typeof b) + ' (expected: function)<br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.0.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution won't work for me but I'll try to use the latest version of Lodash and see if it changes anything! I'll update in consequence. :)

Comment: I'm using Lodash 3.6 and even though it does copy jQuery, I can't use it as I do with jQuery. I tried using `var my$ = _.cloneDeep($);my$('body');` and it will throw an exception. Am I missing something?

Comment: My Lodash 3 test was a complete failure, see revised answer. Also, may I ask why the now-only solution is not an option for you?

Comment: Because I'm writing a plugin and I must keep the size at the minimum, load as few files as possible and don't mess up my clients `<head>` tag by dynamically adding new scripts. I'm looking for an easy way, sad jQuery doesn't provide such helper.

Comment: Well, I added a way of doing this with XHR + eval... but I consider that worse than adding a script tag. Also, you're not going to get around loading the file a second time, because the exported `$` function has access to some closures, which no JS code could even hope to be able to clone. Also, since your code is only a plugin, I assume the "new" jQuery must not replace `$`/`jQuery`, right?

Comment: Yeah, it must not replace an eventual existing jQuery, I'm using `noConflict()` to avoid this already. Thanks for the explanations, I'll try to find a workaround :)